# How to assign an open array of const to a TArray<TVarRec> in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I know that an `array of const` is "translated" as `array of TVarRec` by the compiler so I'm wondering if there is a way to store a copy (or maybe a reference using `const`) of an open array directly, I mean without making a loop to copy every item from the array of const to the `TArray<TVarRec>`. The following code shows what I am trying to do.

```
TAppMessage = class
private
  FMessage: string;
  FArgs: TArray<TVarRec>;
public
  constructor Create(AMessage: string; Args array of const);
  function ToString: string;
end;

constructor TAppMessage.Create(AMessage: string; Args array of const);
begin
  Self.FMessage := AMessage;
  Self.FArgs := Args; //<-- E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.TVarRec>' and 'array of TVarRec'
end;

function TAppMessage.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := Format(Self.FMessage, Self.FArgs);
end;

var AppMsg: TAppMessage;
AppMsg := TAppMessage.Create('A number %d and a text %s', [10, 'foo']);
ShowMessage(AppMsg.ToString);
```

**Is there any way to assign an open array of const to a `TArray<TVarRec>`?**

Note: I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 (Tokyo)

Comment: A reference would be useless since the open array parameter will cease to exist after the call returns. Assignment is not possible because the open array has a different structure (just payload - no length, ref count specifier etc..). I guess you'll have to do the copy yourself.

Comment: I wrote [an article that does that](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html#arrayofconst). See the code at the end of that section.

Comment: FWIW, your parameter is an open array parameter, your FArgs is a TArray<TVarRec>. These **look** the same, but are not the same. Read the "Confusion" part of the article I linked to: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html#confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Do not simply copy the TVarRecs!

I <strike>see</strike> have seen several answers that advise you to copy the `TVarRec`s one by one into a `TArray<TVarRec>`. **That is not enough!**

It will work for values that can directly be stored in the `TVarRec`, like `Integer`s, but it does not work for values that do not fit. These are allocated **on the stack** (in other words: in temporary storage) and then referenced form the `TVarRec`. Take a look at the declaration of `TVarRec`:

```
type
  TVarRec = record { do not pack this record; it is compiler-generated }
    case Integer of
      0: (case Byte of
            vtInteger:       (VInteger: Integer);
            vtBoolean:       (VBoolean: Boolean);
            vtChar:          (VChar: _AnsiChr);
            vtExtended:      (VExtended: PExtended);
{$IFNDEF NEXTGEN}
            vtString:        (VString: _PShortStr);
{$ENDIF !NEXTGEN}
            vtPointer:       (VPointer: Pointer);
            vtPChar:         (VPChar: _PAnsiChr);
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
            vtObject:        (VObject: Pointer);
{$ELSE}
            vtObject:        (VObject: TObject);
{$ENDIF}
            vtClass:         (VClass: TClass);
            vtWideChar:      (VWideChar: WideChar);
            vtPWideChar:     (VPWideChar: PWideChar);
            vtAnsiString:    (VAnsiString: Pointer);
            vtCurrency:      (VCurrency: PCurrency);
            vtVariant:       (VVariant: PVariant);
            vtInterface:     (VInterface: Pointer);
            vtWideString:    (VWideString: Pointer);
            vtInt64:         (VInt64: PInt64);
            vtUnicodeString: (VUnicodeString: Pointer);
         );
      1: (_Reserved1: NativeInt;
          VType:      Byte;
         );
  end;
```

As you can see, types like `Currency`, `Variant` or `ShortString` clearly do not fit in a `TVarRec`, so they are **referenced** (and the true value is placed **on the stack** by the runtime). if you only copy the `TVarRec`s, you don't copy the values, and since these are **only valid during the call**, the reference will be **invalid as soon as the routine ends**. So you will have to **copy these referenced values to your own storage**, e.g.:

```
SetLength(Copies, Length(Values));
for I := 0 to High(Values) do
begin
  Copies[I] := TVarRec(Values[I]);
  case TVarRec(Values[I]).VType of
  ...
    vtExtended:
      begin
        // Copy the referenced Extended to the heap:
        New(Copies[I].VExtended);
        Copies[I].VExtended^ := TVarRec(Values[I]).VExtended^;
      end;
    // etc...
```

etc... You must also take care of proper refcounting for `UnicodeString`s, `AnsiString`s, `Variant`s, interfaces, etc.

***So do not follow the advice of those who tell you to copy the array***!!

You must really make a **deep copy**, as I show [in an article I have written exactly about this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html#code). I can't quote the entire article, but you can find it on my website.

#### Caution

*Don't just copy the code, also read the rest of the section, because you must free the values referenced by the copy array after use, using the function also shown there.*

Answer (score 1):

The array argument passed to `TAppMessage.Create` becomes invalid when that method returns. Hence you cannot hold a reference for lifetime reasons.

You should make a copy.

Comment: Note that it must be a **deep** copy. Many of the value oyu can pass do nit fit in a TVarRec directly, and are allocated on the stack and then referenced in the TVarRec. It is not enugh to only copy the TVarRec, you'll also have to copy the referenced values to your own storage and link to those.